# Generate random samples from a distribution with custom pdf in R?

Tags: r

How can I generate 10,000 random samples in R from a distribution with the pdf f(x) = 3x^2I(0 < x < 1) where I is an indicator function?

Comment: What does 'pdf' refer to?

Answer (score 0):

The cdf will be F(x) = x^3I(0 < x < 1). Using [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), x ~ U(0,1)^(1/3). In R that will be:

```
x <- runif(1e4)^(1/3)
```

Compare the histogram of `x` to the pdf:

```
h <- hist(x)
xlines <- seq(min(h$breaks), max(h$breaks), length.out = 1e4)
lines(xlines, 3*xlines^2*length(x)*diff(h$breaks[1:2]))
```

[image]